# На чём написана программа expect?

Tags: tcl, expect

На странице в википедии, посвящённой программе (и библиотеке) *expect*, [написано](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) (блок с информацией в верхней правой части страницы):

> Written in    Tcl

Но попытавшись найти исходники (как заявлено — на языке *tcl*), максимум, что можно обнаружить (на любом из двух сайтов, упомянутых как официальные: https://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/ и https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/dir?ci=tip) — это исходники **на языке c**.

Где же обещанное «*written in tcl*»?

---

Это не вопросо-ответ. Я действительно не знаю ответа. И вообще всегда так и считал, что программа *expect* написана именно на *tcl*.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос вызван ошибкой на странице в Википедии, которая уже исправлена. Таким образом устранено само основание для появления этого вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Программа *expect* действительно [написана на языке C](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/dir?ci=tip), и лишь использует  [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) в качестве «языка расширения».

А в Википедии одиннадцать лет назад была внесена [правка](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Expect&type=revision&diff=235749386&oldid=234851239), согласно которой якобы программа написана на языке [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl). (и за всё это время никто не обратил внимания! ну или корректирующая ошибку правка была отклонена по какой-то причине — искать в истории больно долго).

Внёс соответствующую корректировку в [англо-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) и [русскоязычной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) статьях.

Comment: @sanmai, пожалуйста, не надо при редактировании изменять суть сообщения.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, вам не понравились заглавные буквы? Или ссылка на исходники?

Comment: @sanmai, пожалуйста, не изменяйте сути сообщения. хотите поправить регистр букв — я не возражаю. но суть, пожалуйста, не трогайте.

Comment: если считаете, что ответ недостаточно полон — напишите, пожалуйста, свой вариант.

Comment: Без проблем, да будет мой ответ.

Comment: @sanmai, спасибо!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а я что-то не понял, в чём здесь было изменение сути?

Comment: @andreymal: 1. засоряющая (потому что не делает ответ ни лучше, ни понятнее) информация о том, что программа expect является ещё и интерпретатором (как раз благодаря тому, что, как и написано в ответе, tcl используется в ней  как «язык расширения»). 2. не относящаяся к делу ещё одна ссылка на исходники (она и косвенно приведена в вопросе, и прямо — в первом из ответов), подменяющая задуманную мною ссылку на метку "c" (гораздо более уместную здесь, как я это себе представляю).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin про интерпретатор видимо да, а вот ссылка-пруф по-моему была вполне уместной, в то время как ссылка на метку никак не дополняет ответ и фактически бесполезна чуть более чем полностью

Comment: @andreymal, да, видимо, я зря не перечислил прямо в вопросе обе ссылки, называемые (в разных местах) «официальными» (есть ещё третья — expect.nist.gov, ныне не действующая). исправил недоработку. по поводу метки у меня своя точка зрения.

Comment: "засоряющая информация о том, что программа expect является ещё и интерпретатором" - вот если бы вы так сразу написали, много было бы понятней что не так с правками, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

На странице в Википедии определенно ошибка. [Программа `expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) написана на языке C, в чем можно [убедиться посмотрев исходники](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/dir?ci=tip).

(Программы же, которые *выполняет* `expect`, действительно должны быть написаны на языке Tcl ([примеры в документации](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)), из-за чего могла возникнуть путаница. Tcl для `expect` не просто «язык расширения», это основной способ использования возможностей `expect`, но это не означает что сама программа `expect` оказывается написана на Tcl. Это не так.)

Comment: кто-то и заминусовал. вероятно, тот, кто, как и я считает версию типа «emacs может интерпретировать скрипты на lisp-е, значит и сам на нём написан» не очень-то достоверной.

Comment: Таки их каких слов появляется такая версия? Открытым текстом пишу, синим по белому, что написана на языке С. Синим по белому - потому что ссылка на исходники. Вы что имели ввиду?

Comment: вот это: «Программы же, которые выполняет expect, действительно написаны на языке TCL, из-за чего могла возникнуть путаница.» (сравните с тем, что написано в моём комментарии выше по поводу emacs-а и lisp-а).

Comment: "Программы же, которые выполняет expect, действительно написаны на языке TCL" - это факт.

Comment: верно. но гипотеза о причине ошибки в википедии — мало достоверна (как мне представляется).

Comment: У нас есть другая гипотеза? «Никогда не приписывайте злому умыслу то, что вполне можно объяснить глупостью»

Comment: да пожалуйста: один из трёх сайтов (которые в разных местах указываются как «официальные» сайты программы expect), является сайтом разработчиков интерпретатора tcl. ну, значит, и expect на tcl написана. p.s. данная гипотеза столь же недостоверна

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96181/discussion-between-sanmai-and-aleksandr-barakin).